# What would be a good way to replace a static class used to hold Application settings?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application that uses a static class to store settings:

```cs
namespace ABC
{
    public static class MS 
    {
        public static bool abc;
        public static bool def;
        ...
    }
}
```

When the app starts up it goes to the database and updates some of these settings.

I have been told that holding them in a static class is not ideal for when I am doing bindings and adding notification so I'm thinking I should new a class and the hold them in an instance. If that's the case can someone give me some advice.  Should I do that when the application starts up and should it be in the constructor of the App() if that is the best way to do it then how can I do this. Any small 4-5 line example would be a big help

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static xxx

    public App()
    {
        AS.appUpdated = "Feb 1, 2017";
        AS.appVersion = "0.1";
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new MS.MainPage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at James Montemagno's settings plugin.

https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

This abstracts away a lot of the plumbing around settings and persisting them locally. Calling one of your settings from anywhere in your application then becomes as simple as calling `Settings.MySettingName`.

When it comes to binding these values to a view I would always create a property for them in your view model that simply returns the value from the settings. If need be you can put them in a base viewmodel and go from there.

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

}

public class BaseViewModel
{
     public bool SettingA => Settings.SettingA;
     public bool SettingB => Settings.SettingB;
}
```

Comment: The problem for me is the settings are shared all around the application. So in more than one view model.

Comment: You can create a base viewmodel that all your view models inherit from and expose them from there.

Comment: I like the idea of the base view model.  Can you explain to me what the => syntax does. I am not familiar with that.  I also have some background processes (no view with them) can I use the same base view model for those background processes?

Comment: Basically that's a language shortcut for a readonly property that simply returns a value immediately like you would normally write as follows: `public bool SettingA {get { return Settings.SettingA; }}`. Any other process could directly call `Settings.SettingA` using the Settings plugin I mentioned directly instead of through a view model.